# How should boost::lockfree::spsc_queue's read_available and write_available be used?

Tags: c++, boost, lock-free

[Boost documentation for `spsc_queue`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html) says:

**`read_available()`**: Thread-safe and wait-free, should only be called from the producer thread

**`write_available()`**: Thread-safe and wait-free, should only be called from the consumer thread

I would expect the most common use case to be just the other way around: producer thread (thread *writing* data to the queue) would need `write_available()`, and consumer thread (thread *reading* data from the queue) would need `read_available()`.

If I need to know how much I can write to the queue in the producer thread, should I use `QUEUE_CAPACITY - read_available()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any kind of size assessment is going to be a race in the lockfree world.

Simple reason being that the size might be changed on other threads before you act on the "measured size".

Single-Producer/Single-Consumer is *special* in the sense that the consumer *knows* nobody else can read from the the queue (so "read_available" will never decrease *unless the consumer reads it itself*). Similarly for the producer side.

**It is clear that `write_available` is what you need**. Sure, it could be *more* by the time you actually write, but you can't get more accurate. At least it will never be *less* (after all there is only 1 producer thread).

> **Note** that the documentation appears to be in error (swapping the allowed threads)
>
> This made me double check, and sure enough they use the functions internally in the expected ways (contradicting the erronous documentation claim):
>
> ```
> ConstIterator push(ConstIterator begin, ConstIterator end, T * internal_buffer, size_t max_size)
> {
>     const size_t write_index = write_index_.load(memory_order_relaxed);  // only written from push thread
>     const size_t read_index  = read_index_.load(memory_order_acquire);
>     const size_t avail = write_available(write_index, read_index, max_size);
> ```

I heartily suggest using the range-push shown here to automatically push the exact number of items possible. E.g.:

```
auto b = messages.begin(), e = messages.end();
do {
    b = a.push(b, e)
} while (b != e);
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. It seems the documentation is already fixed in develop branch: https://github.com/boostorg/lockfree/commit/f7bb4d14022426fa5c6affc5f5970ecbe855d061

Comment: @khuttun Thanks! That is solid confirmation. (Makes you wonder though ... o.O)